# Specifying Facebook send title, url and image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, forwarding

I have a page that lists various tracks/music, and would like each one to have its own like / send button.

The issue I'm having is I use domain forwarding + host masking, which means the title in the send request is always the title I've specified in my domain forwarding, never the title of the actual page, and if I use its true url, not the masked version I get the right title but underneath you now get the url for wrong website not the masked url.

Is it possible to specify these in the code for the like / send button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the proper URL with the href property on the [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).  For the title and image, set the [open graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) og:title and og:image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intelligent forwarding service that will mimic META tags of the URL it will forward itself to, this way, that link can have useful info too